# can winpexpect get the same result with subprocess?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, expect

I want to communicate with the subprocess on Windows, and I find winpexpect is one way can help to complete the task. The codes is as following

```
>>> import winpexpect
>>> subproc=winpexpect.winspawn('python')
>>> subproc.expect('>>>')
```

and a TimeOut exception is raised. Can someone give me some advices?

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>subproc=subprocess.Popen('python')
```

codes using subprocess can really start python program, however winpexpect doesn't seem to start

Comment: Maybe you don't get what you expect, e.g. the >>>. Maybe echo the output you get and verify it contains what you expect().

Comment: @schlenk: the getecho() method can not be used on Windows. termios moudle is only available for unix.

Comment: Not sure about winpexpect, i just know the Tcl expect for windows needed to do really weird stuff to work properly (e.g. act like a debugger). But you could try to 'force' interactive mode by running with 'python -i' as i saw no code in winpexpect that forced it on Windows (unlike Tcl's winexpect), and a python running in a pipe does not show a prompt, so your expect('>>>') will fail.

Comment: I saw an example on the winpexpect google group for a logfile:                      .     c = winspawn('telnet kabul.sodalia.it', logfile=logfile)         .what does your logfile contain when you try it this way?